# 2 monitor setup, copied screen

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, screen

I have two monitors for my PC. - This problem only started recently, up until a couple a days ago it was fine. I am using the latest open source nvidia driver.
The problem is that the right screen in a duplicate of the left screen. How do I fix this so that I have one left screen and a separate right screen?

Comment: Have you changed anything at all recently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to "search" and type "displays", then open it. Uncheck "Mirror displays" on the right.

Comment: Atleast that's how I fix it for ubuntu 13.04 and mint 15.

Comment: They are both already unchecked.

Comment: maybe try "utility tweak" i dont know much about it though. You can get it with "run a command"